# PDO Transactions: What happens to another script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

It is said on the PHP docs site that:

> while the transaction is active, you are guaranteed that no one else
>   can make changes while you are in the middle of your work

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

The question is: if I start transaction in Script A and then Script B tries to makes any changes before Script A commits -- what would be the outcome for the Script B? Will it "wait"? Will it fail with error? What exactly?

Comment: It will block until it can gain access to what it needs

Comment: I think you should read literature on database transactions. This is something all database programmers should learn about.

Comment: Barman, thank you for the insight. I don't believe that a MySQL book would describe how this or that PHP library(mysql, mysqli, PDO, etc.) would "react into PHP code" (PHP execution can fail, delayed, an exception can be thrown, etc. -- it's not SQL behavior here) when facing a locked transaction. Besides, there are controversial statements like "all that PDO::startTransaction does is disabling auto-commit" and like that.

Comment: @pilat I think you're confusing what PHP is responsible for and what your DBMS is responsible for to arrive at that conclusion. PHP is just a client to your DBMS. If it fails, all that happens is that the client connection to the database server is severed. This is equivalent to you closing your mysql command prompt in the middle of sending a statement. A transaction, however, is autonomous at the COMMIT level. So once the commit statement is received by the server, it doesn't matter what happens to PHP. If PHP dies before a commit is sent, the transaction is rolled back by the database server

Comment: A MySQL book would **definitely** describe what you *need* to know about how transactions work at the server-level, which is all you should care about here. What happens at the client level is simple. The client just sends the server queries and receives data. A failure at the client level is obvious. All that can happen is that either the client doesn't send a query or it doesn't receive a response from the server, but it's never responsible for carrying out the actual queries. So that's moot in regards to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are controlled at the DBMS level, not by PHP. So if something is blocked, it's done by your DBMS. This varies, because different database engines block at different levels. For example, MySQL MyISAM engine will lock at the table level whereas the MySQL InnoDB engine can block at row-level. Locking can also happen at a per-session or global basis depending on how you configure your DBMS and how the transaction is performed. PDO only implements the driver for your vendor-specific DBMS so it has no real say in all of that.

Comment: Right. It depends on what you are actually doing inside the transaction, not the transaction itself. There is no mention from the op who or what is going on in A or B. So, to me, the question is nebulous.

Comment: Ok. I have MySQL InnoDB table. Transaction starts, I update/insert number of rows (REPLACE INTO ...), then transaction is committed. I need to know how to make sure that another script, trying to change anything in few of blocked rows, won't fail or "forget" to do its work.

Comment: There's nothing for *you* to do. The "*make sure ... it won't fail*" part is the responsibility of your database management system. With InnoDB you have something called a data file and a log file. Your DBMS keeps track of every transaction and only writes the changes to your data files *after* you commit. So a rollback just reads from the log files and will *undo* history to get back to the exact restore point your db was at before the transaction took place. Multiple threads conducting multiple transactions don't break this process. This is what the DBMS was built for.

Comment: Sherif, let say, DBMS rejects such transaction (I don't know, it's just one of possible outcomes). It means I need to tell user that his action did not have any effect and that s/he should try again later. Right? I can't simply pretend that everything went well. So, I need to know about rejection in my PHP script, as well.